# pandas вставка функции в url запрос

Tags: python, pandas

Привет, есть код:

```
okex = requests.get('https://www.okex.com/api/v1/ticker.do?symbol=ltc_btc')
ok = pd.DataFrame(okex.json())
res  = (ok.loc['buy']['ticker'])
print (res)
```

В первой строке url адрес. Далее, я вытаскиваю из полученных данных столбец и строку.
Мне нужно заменить "ltc_btc" в первой строке на свою функцию, в которой много значений:

```
fun = [ltc_btc, eth_btc, rpx_btc]
```

Это нужно, чтобы не печатать много строк с requests.
Данные, в таком случае, насколько я понимаю должны будут вывестись в столбец из различных значений.

Comment: к pandas это слабое отношение имеет. Всё зависит, какое конкретное API у обменника¶ В сторону: различные ICO мне пирамиды Мавроди напоминают.

Comment: вы можете привести пример того, что вы хотите получить на выходе (в результате)?